# How to convert pandas DataFrame into a dictionary with specific column as key that contains duplicate value?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert DataFrames into dictionaries. I have a column to use as the key, and other columns should be represented as a list of values for each key. However, I have duplicate values in key columns.

Here is an example DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'SL': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                    'SITECODE': ['CMCND1', 'CPHGN7', 'LXRPR1', 'LXRPR1', 'LXRPR1'],
                    'TECH': ['3G', '2G', '4G', '3G', '4G'],
                    'PRIORITY': ['P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P3', 'P3']})
```

The desired Output and key column name is `SITECODE`:

```json
{'CMCND1': ['1', '3G', 'P1'],
 'CPHGN7': ['2', '2G', 'P2'],
 'LXRPR1': ['3', '4G', 'P2'],['4', '3G', 'P3'],['5', '4G', 'P3']}
```

I have tried using the following formula, but it does not give me the desired output.

`df.set_index('SITECODE').T.to_dict('list')`

It doesn't group the duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

You expected output is invalid - you probably want dictionary where values are list of lists:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby("SITECODE")
    .apply(lambda g: g.values.tolist(), include_groups=False)
    .to_dict()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "CMCND1": [["1", "3G", "P1"]],
    "CPHGN7": [["2", "2G", "P2"]],
    "LXRPR1": [["3", "4G", "P2"], ["4", "3G", "P3"], ["5", "4G", "P3"]],
}
```

Comment: no i don't want values are list of lists. before raising the question here, i have checked with several ai those all provides similar list of list as value.

Comment: thanks for correction. yes i am expecting impossible..

Comment: This is the difference between ai and human programer. ai keeps trying but did not told me that i am expecting impossible result. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple dictionary comprehension with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
out = {k: g.to_numpy().tolist() for k, g in
       df.groupby('SITECODE')[['SL', 'TECH', 'PRIORITY']]}
```

Output:

```
09

{'CMCND1': [['1', '3G', 'P1']],
 'CPHGN7': [['2', '2G', 'P2']],
 'LXRPR1': [['3', '4G', 'P2'], ['4', '3G', 'P3'], ['5', '4G', 'P3']]}
```

Comment: the desired dictionary values should not be the nested list

Comment: What is the expected output then? You example is not valid python.